# Image Size getting Smaller after Converting to Bytes

Tags: android, image

In my android application i want to convert image into byte array and encode into string so that  i can save it on database. But after compressing image it's size becomes too small..i want to keep original size.. please help me..

```
  final Bitmap image=(images.get(position));

ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
                image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bytes);

                byte[] b = bytes.toByteArray();
                 encodedImageString = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Comment: remove image.compress() statement.

Comment: Size in kb or size in width x height?

Comment: lolx..bro then how should i convert into byte?? after removing it..

Comment: size in kb @jeffrey...how can i convert to byte here without using image.compress

Comment: image s Bitmap type...post edited..thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to store it in the database without compression:

```
Bitmap bitmap; // obtain bitmap object
int size = bitmap.getRowBytes() * bitmap.getHeight(); 
ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocate(size); 
bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(b); 
byte[] bytes = new byte[size];
b.get(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
```

Then you can store `bytes` in the database.